# Using StoreKit to display info about other apps. (not in-app purchases)

Tags: ios, storekit

Is it possible to retrieve info (SKProduct) about my other apps on appstore within my new app or is it only possible to retrieve info about in-app purchases? If so, must the app be "in-app purchases"-enabled?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple provides Search API: http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html

Just create NSObject class that implements NSURLConnection with desired parameters and retrieve response with JSON decode.